# I, cannot set property 'IS_CHECK' of undefined TYPE ERROR

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a checkbox that when it selected everything should be selected. I handled the code using this [link](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/select-all-deselect-all-checkbox.html) with angular 2 example.

But I get an error called "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'IS_CHECK' of undefined"

How do I resolve this error. I can't seem to fix this.

Here's what I did.

html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <span class="btnRefresh">
      <i 
        class="fa fa-refresh" 
        [ngClass]="{'fa-spin': RefreshAnimate}" 
        (click)="OnRefrshClick()" 
        style="margin-top: 15px;">
      </i>
    </span>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center">Application No</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">RPU No</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Name with Initials</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">NIC/PP No</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="selectedAll" 
          [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" 
          id="selectedAll" 
          (change)="CheckAll()">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr 
      *ngFor="let transfer of AllTransfers | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: _page, totalItems: _total}; let i = index">
      <td style="text-align: center">{{transfer.AA_APPLICATION_NO}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">{{transfer.AA_PREV_RPU_NO}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">{{transfer.AA_NAME_WITH_INTL}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">{{transfer.AA_NIC_NO || transfer.AA_PASSPORT_NO}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          [(ngModel)]="transfer.IS_CHECK" 
          (change)="checkIfAllSelected()" 
          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The typescript.

```
selectedAll: boolean = false;

CheckAll() {
  for (var i = 0; this.AllTransfers.length; i++) {
    this.AllTransfers[i].IS_CHECK = this.selectedAll;
    console.log(this.selectedAll);
  }
}

checkIfAllSelected() {
  this.selectedAll = this.AllTransfers.every(function(item: any) {
    return item.IS_CHECK == true;
  });
}
```

The JSON object is

```
Data: [{
  "AA_APPL_ID": 114731,
  "AA_NIC_NO": "835678904V",
  "AA_NAME_WITH_INTL": "R.DAYARATHNE",
  "AA_APPLICTION_NO": "SYS12132132",
  "IS_CHECK": false
}]
```

This is the way I tried to implement the select all checkbox using the link. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `i < this.AllTransfers.length` to the for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.AllTransfers.length; i++) {
  this.AllTransfers[i].IS_CHECK = this.selectedAll;
  console.log(this.selectedAll);
}
```

Comment: usually, in ts you use this.allTransfers.forEach(c=>{c.IS_CHECK=this.selectedAll}) -in general we not use yet a "for" to go thought an array else forEach or map.- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach -

Comment: @Franklin Pious Thanks it works now. That was a silly mistake.